# How to calculate newTrades?

Tags: mysql, sql

i.e. when new trades are in the current date trade list but not in the previous date trade list.
I have tried

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of New Trades"
FROM  TRADE_REPORT
WHERE business_date='2018-05-08' and excluded='false'
MINUS
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of New Trades"
FROM TRADE_REPORT
WHERE business_date='2018-05-07'
and excluded='false'
```

But it did not worked

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a `NOT IN` clause capturing non-matches of IDs between the two days.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of New Trades"
FROM TRADE_REPORT t1
WHERE t1.business_date='2018-05-08' AND t1.excluded='false'
AND t1.ID NOT IN
    (SELECT sub.ID
     FROM TRADE_REPORT sub
     WHERE sub.business_date='2018-05-07' AND sub.excluded='false')
```

Comment: No problem Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

No. `MINUS` is a set operator, not an arithmetic operator, and it is not even available in MySQL. I think you want:

```
select count(*)
from trade_report tr
where tr.business_date = '2018-05-08' and tr.excluded = 'false' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from trade_report tr2
                  where tr2.? = tr.? and
                        tr2.business_date = '2018-05-07' and
                        tr2.excluded = 'false'
                 );
```

The `?` is for the id of what you want compare from one day to the next.

Comment: Fo eg: if like on '2018-05-07' I have trades with id's 1,2,3,4,5 and  on '2018-05-08' I have trades with id's 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 then for new trades I will get 6,7,8 in the output for  '2018-05-08'